# A doubt regarding the Minimum equivalent depth-d Formula problem

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

Minimum equivalent depth-d expression ($MEE_d$) is defined as:

Given a depth-d Boolean formula $F$ and an integer $k$, is there an equivalent depth-d formula of size at most $k$? For every $d\geq3$, the problem $MEE_d$ is $Σ^P_2$-complete under polynomial-time Turing reductions.

Now, the depth of the formula is by definition the length of the longest path in the boolean circuit of the given boolean formula. But, I am unclear about the 'size' in this specific problem:

**Doubt:** In some places, the 'size' of the boolean formula is the number of gates in the boolean circuit of the given boolean formula (with each gate having unlimited fan-in). But in other places 'size' is defined as occurrences of variables in boolean formula $F$. So which is it?

It should make much of a difference as we can change $k$ depending on the definition chosen but still what is the formal definition here.

And is it correct to assume each gate has unlimited fan-in?